# Highcharts How to update all series with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a function used to get data for my chart by ajax but I have a problem when I want to update it.

I would like to do something like that

chart.series = data;

but it's not working.

And with JSON.parse(data) I have an error but there is no problem with the JSON I think.

Example

```
[{ name : "<0.5s", marker:{enabled:false}, data : [[21231,1]]},{ name : "<20s", marker:{enabled:false}, data : [[21231,1]]}]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To set the series data dynamically, you need to call setData:

```
chart.series[0].setData(seriesData, false);
```

This just sets the data in an existing series. You wouldn't set all the other series options every time.

Comment: ok i had a problem because i have all the series in my json but now I use another webservice to get just the data and not the options and everything is working fine. thanks

Comment: for 50k series its very slow, it takes 13-15 seconds to redraw chart